False Discovery Rate (FDR) correction on variables not analyzed simultaneously
I've collected data from a nutritional clinical trial involving 50 individuals divided into 2 groups: Control and Treatment. At baseline and after 1 month, the nutrient composition of the habitual diet (i.e., proteins, carbohydrates, etc.), blood pressure, glycemia, cholesterol, and triglycerides were collected.
The pairwise time points (Δ1month - baseline) difference between the Treatment and Control groups were assessed using an Independent-sample T-test.
My question is, despite having analyzed the data independently, do I have to adjust the p-values for FDR?
Thanks
